# All the values present are not getting added to the dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, foreach

All the values present are not getting added to the dictionary in c#
the following is the code snippet so far :

```
 XmlNodeList Bugs_filter = Bugs.SelectNodes("/criteria/includeFilterSets/filterSet/filter");
    if (Bugs_filter != null)
    {

        foreach (XmlNode BNode in Bugs_filter)
        {
            string data = BNode.SelectSingleNode("/criteria/includeFilterSets/filterSet/filter/filterName").InnerText;
            string aggregate = BNode.SelectSingleNode("/criteria/includeFilterSets/filterSet/filter/value").InnerText;

            {   
                 Dict.Add(data,aggregate);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are total 3 values present in the 'Bugs_Filter' whereas when it comes in loop second time it picks up the first value only.Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Please refer to the XML from which i am extracting the values :

```
 <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><criteria><includeFilterSets><filterSet><filter><filterId>42</filterId>
    <filterName>PRODUCT_ID</filterName><operator><id>1</id><name>Equals</name></operator><value>1113</value></filter><filter><filterId>41</filterId>
    <filterName>FAMILY_ID</filterName><operator><id>1</id><name>Equals</name></operator><value>ESG</value></filter><filter><filterId>3</filterId><filterName>VERSION_NAME</filterName>
    <operator><id>1</id><name>Equals</name></operator><value>4.5</value></filter></filterSet></includeFilterSets><excludeFilterSets/><ordering/>
    <bugGroupSearchMode>0</bugGroupSearchMode><caseSensitive>true</caseSensitive><entityToSearch><id>1</id><name>BUG</name></entityToSearch></criteria>
```

Please note that i am extracting the PRODUCT_ID,FAMILY_ID and VERSION_NAME.

Comment: please use the editor and reformat that code thanks

Comment: Some of your code is missing and it's be helpful to see the XML

Comment: could you post the 3 values here

Comment: Is `Bugs_Filter` equal to `null`? Is `Bugs_filter` non-empty? Show us the declaration for `Dict`. Show us how it's being consumed.

Comment: why not debug putting a break point inside your foreach loop & see if the values are really getting populated?

Answer (score 1):

please notice what are you trying to do here:
in the `foreach` statement you have the `filter` nodes, and under them you search for the whole path "/criteria/includeFilterSets/filterSet/filter/filterName". you won't get to the right nodes like that.

instead, use `BNode.ChildNodes[1]` and `BNode.ChildNodes[3]` respectfully

```
string data = BNode.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
string aggregate = BNode.ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
```

or even better:

```
string data = BNode["filterName"].InnerText;
string aggregate = BNode["value"].InnerText;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried?

```
string data = BNode.SelectSingleNode("./filterName").InnerText;
string aggregate = BNode.SelectSingleNode("./value").InnerText;
```

Since you give the full path it starts searching from root element each time. By `.` you say something like "filterName node under this node" where `this` is current `BNode`